# Questionable migration and loosing upvotes

Tags: support, migration, votes

I stumbled upon a [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27888/what-is-the-state-of-cryptographic-obfuscation-in-2015), were a user had some questions about obfuscation. His/her ideas were based-upon an article and academic research on that topic. It seemed to me that there are severe problems in understanding by the user and tried my best to explain the problems and why certain ideas would not work in the way expected. I also tried to clear some confusion about terminology which was apparent after a few comments of the OP.

It seemed that 4 people agreed with me on Security StackExchange since I had four up-votes. Now for some reason this question was migrated to Crypto StackExchange despite that the actual problem is not much of a cryptographic problem but rather the misunderstanding of the user that obfuscation=encryption. As the question is mostly about actual practical application of obfuscation with cryptography, I think it is not appropriate for Crypto.
It also seems like I lost three up-votes due to this migration.

How do I get help from a moderator in such a situation? I believe it would greatly help the user to have this on Security StackExchange as there are some very grave misconceptions which should be greatly avoided in real life implementation.

I do not care much about the lost votes but it just seems that there is no benefit for anybody when such a question is migrated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The author asked for it to be migrated.

After I tried to sort through all the comments and answers to determine the best fit, it still wasn't 100% clear to me to migrate or not. The deciding elements for me was the author's request, and the referenced article was from a cryptography author.

It's possible the Crypto mods and our mods might need to sort this out, given the odd subject matter, but the intent was to follow the wishes of the author as well as to keep to the standards of both sites.

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer. Hopefully it helps the author.

Comment: @John no problem. Don't be afraid to ask us Mods why we made decisions. We're human, we make mistakes, and sometimes we need to flip coins. If we mess something up, we try to make up for it the best way we can.